# Warn if at least one value not empty

Tags: jquery

I have a set of form fields generated via a loop:

```
foreach ($arrays as $listValue) {
    echo '
    <div>
       <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="field[]">
    </div>';
}
<a href="#" id="myLink">link</a>
```

I also have a link below, that when clicked calls a jQuery function.

I'd like to add a check and display a warning (alert is fine) if there's at least one value present in the form fields when I click my link.

Answer (score 5):

```
if($('input[value!=""]').length > 0) {
    //at least one field is filled out 
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about serializing the whole form at creation, the comparing it to the current serialized value, but this is so much simpler.

Comment: Note that it will consider a single space as having that field filled in, which might not be what you want depending on implementation.

Comment: @Marek Karbarz This looks great but is there a way to check for values based on fields' name? I have aother form elements on the page that can have values.

Comment: I'd say if you really need to, go with @Abe Petrillo's `each()` way of things, you can trim out whitespace before checking. Just make sure you `return false` after the first hit to break out of `each()`.

Comment: I know how to trim with PHP. Is there a way to do it in JS too?

Comment: @santa, you could use jQuery's `$.trim(str)` function to remove white spaces, but in that case you will need to go with Abe's suggestion.  As for using a field name - you can put in any selector in place of or in addition to `input`.  You could do `$('input[name=someName][value!=""])`

Comment: @santa - quick note about the use of `[]` in your name.  You will need to escape that with double slashes in the sample selector I included: `$('input[name=someName\\[\\]][value!=""]')`

Comment: The more I think about it the more I am convinced that just warning a user is OK, but it would be so much better preserve the field with input in addition to adding new. But I think this is should be a separate question, because it is quite different from this original post.

Comment: @Marek Karbarz I have created a spin-off question from this one. I decided to change the behavior of my page, while integrating some of the suggestions from this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144025/detect-field-with-value-and-save-it-in-addition-to-new-posted-results

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':input').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() != '')
     {
        alert('warning');
     }
})
```